# Bring two handbags worth $400 into India duty free

Tags: india, indian-citizens, duty-free

I am an Indian citizen residing in Canada for the last 4 months. If I carry two new handbags to India worth $300 approx, would I be required to pay import duty. I checked the website and it says that you can bring valuables worth Rs.35000 (approx. $600). I just want to make sure that new handbags won't be a problem.

Comment: Total value. And no other dutiable goods in my opinion. Its just  that one of the bags is a designer bag which I nabbed for a really good price. I am just concerned that they might consider the price back in Indian rather than the price I got it for.

Comment: Yes. Although I bought these online and you never know with Indian officials. They are not exactly the reasonable type.

Comment: I guess I will take my chances. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22689/discussion-between-thenoob-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 3):

> If I carry two new handbags to India worth $300 approx, would I be required to pay import duty.
>
> I checked the website and it says that you can bring valuables worth Rs.35000 (approx. $600).

Is $300 more than $600?  I think you just answered your own question there.

Comment: +1, but zeros *are* a relatively late arrival. So perhaps not.

Comment: On the other hand, zero as a number *was* invented in India, so you'd figure Customs there would have heard of it.